# Getting error when deployed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: azure, go, azure-functions, socketexception

I have created an Azure Function in Go. The function is working properly in local machine. But, when I deploy it to Azure, I am getting the below exception:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Inner exception method is: `System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__1.MoveNext`

Error log is here: https://github.com/mpurusottamc/azurefunc-go/blob/master/errorlog.json

local.settings.json file has below code:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<proper storage link>"
    }
}
```

host.json file has golang executable reference as the worker.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    "httpWorker": {
        "description": {
            "defaultExecutablePath": "hello.exe"
        }
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
}
```

My code is hosted in github here: https://github.com/mpurusottamc/azurefunc-go

deploy.sh file contains the deployment script.

Followed this reference article: https://itnext.io/write-azure-functions-in-any-language-with-the-http-worker-34d01f522bfd

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just tried your app and deployed to a Windows consumption function app and it worked. (needed to add `--force` to the deployment) What version of Go are you using to compile? There were some versions that didn't work in the Azure App Service sandbox that the apps run in. 1.14.2 and higher should work. (I'm building with 1.14.5 on macOS)

Comment: If you're still having issues after updating Go, can you please file an issue here and tag me (anthonychu). Thanks! https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues

Comment: @AnthonyChu after i updated golang to 1.14 and applied --force in the deployment script, it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated golang version to 1.14 on my machine. And also applied --force in the deployment script and that resolved the issue for me.

go.mod is updated like this:

```
module hello

go 1.14
```

deployment script updated to include --force argument

> func azure functionapp publish hellogoapp --force